# How to access object parameters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I am trying to figure out how to properly parse some values returned from the linkedIn JavaScript API.

At present I am using the following code to loop through and print the objects returned.

```
for(var position in profile.positions)
{
    profHTML = profHTML + profile.positions[position];
}
```

The result (which is getting me part of the way to figuring it out is:

```
 11[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Essentially its the # of objects (which seems to be the first thing returned) and then each of the objects.

According to what is returned when I do a console log in Chrome this code is returning an array of objects which contain an object named "company". Company contains 4 attributes ("id","industry","name","type")

I gather that profile.positions[position] is the reference to the element returned however I am not sure of the syntax to access the company object and attribute while looping.

I am also not sure what would be the best practice to avoid trying to reference the field on the very first loop which returns the number of objects.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you give the full JSON output returned? It is hard to deduce exactly what structure you are describing. Also, never use a `for`-`in` loop for arrays: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#array.general

Comment: How do I provide the full JSON output returned? I'll be happy to post.

Comment: Paste it into the question...

Comment: Ok to Domenic I tried several variations with the assistance from feedback on here. This code can grab a specific field:
profile.positions.values[0].company.id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, use a [regular `for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), not a [`for...in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), to iterate over an array.

```
var positions = profile.positions,
    position;

for(var i=0; i<positions.length; i++)
{
    position = positions[i];
    profHTML = profHTML + position;
}
```

Now, to access one of the properties of the `position`, just use a [member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) (`.` or `[]`):

```
var positions = profile.positions,
    company;

for(var i=0; i<positions.length; i++)
{
    company = positions[i].company;
    console.log(company.id, company.industry, company.name, company.type);
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's an array, an array's `.length` is not enumerable. It's probably custom created array-like object(e.g. `{0: 0, length: 1}`). The same still applies though that `for` loop should be used.

Comment: Also, remember to always cache the length of the array, rather than accessing it each iteration. It seems like it wouldn't make much of a difference, but it does. See http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loops/2 for proof.

Comment: According to the stats from the jsPerf test I linked to, it is only slower to cache the length in one or two specific versions of browsers, and not by much. The more likely result is that it will be faster for most browsers. I agree it is not as important as the distinction between `for ( in )` and `for (var i)`, but if you include it in example code, it helps encourage best practices, IMHO.

Comment: IMO caching `length` is a microoptimization that obfuscates the code.